# Issue with Iframe function

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe that contains an upload.php file in my page. So i want my page to refresh once when an upload in the iframe is complete. However, my page refreshes continuously whether or not i have clicked the upload button..Help please
Here is my code...

```
<script>
var up = document.getElementById("upload");
function iloaded(){
    window.location.reload();
}
up.onload = iloaded();
</script>
```

and here is the iframe

```
<iframe style="display:none" id="upload" src="upload.php"></iframe>
```

the upload is successful though but the page refresh is the issue here..

Comment: Well the iframe does load with your page and that causes it to trigger iloaded function

Comment: you can't use `reload` function on `onload` event. you need to put a condition there (if file uploaded), so it reloads only after the condition is met

Comment: the solution will be to dynamically create iframe when you need to upload and point it to upload.php

Comment: You're infinitely looping the loading of your parent page, because every time your page loads, then you also load the iframe, which then triggers the reload of the parent page and you repeat the cycle again. Trigger your reload on some other condition that can't be repeated on a refresh of the page. Test some Boolean variable that defaults to false on the load of the page, but is true only after an upload is complete. Or, simply don't refresh the page. You shouldn't have to, if you've designed it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer simply add this code to the upload.php file and leave out all the other js functions.
Here is the code..

```
if(upload==true){?>
<script>
window.top.location.reload();
</script>
<?php}?>
```

Does the job.